# How is the Jacobian an approximation?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I read in a tutorial: [Jacobian](http://booksite.elsevier.com/andrilli/elementary/content/jacobian.pdf) that the Jacobian provides an approximation to a mapping by way of a parallelogram. In other words, if I have a rectangular area and I transform it to polar coordinates, then the determinant of the Jacobian yields an approximation to the area. However, this confuses me because I always viewed the determinant of the Jacobian as the stretching factor inside any change of variables. How can it be an approximation if it yields exact results?

Comment: The Jacobian is not an approximation *per se*, but you can use it to linearize something, a bit the same way a tangent linearizes a curv. The linearization is a first-order approximation.

Comment: If the map is linear to start with, then its best linear approximation is itself and the absolute value of the Jacobian determinant is precisely the factor by which areas of parallelograms are stretched.

Comment: If the rectangle is small but nonzero, then the determinant of the Jacobian is approximately the area ratio (of image to source). In the limit as the size of the parallelogram goes to zero, the approximation becomes exact. It's the latter you use when integrating.